# Throttle Position Sensor: Complete failure, then starts working again?

Tags: throttle-position-sensor

Vehicle: 2002 Hyundai XG350 L

Today while driving to work on the Interstate, my check engine light clicked on and suddenly my gas pedal seemed to just stop working. I managed to coast off an exit and stop near a service station. The mechanic hooked it up and it showed a problem with the Throttle Position Sensor.

However, immediately after turning off and restarting the car, it starts up and seems to just run fine. I've had numerous other strange electrical-type problems with this car, and I worry that the TPS failure is just the latest victim (or symptom, rather).

Are there any other reasons the TPS might report a problem during a diagnostic? If it IS a bad TPS, why would it just stop working althogether, and then start working again once I restart the car?

Answer (score 1):

Are there any other electrical problems? When you restart the car the problem can still be there, but it resets. If there are other electrical problems, these could be the culprit simply affect the sensor.